# Partially unnest a list

Tags: r, list, lapply, purrr

I have a list of class `bt` hat can contain a list of class `bt_list`, and want to unnnest the `bt_list` elements. The example below does what I want, but the code is ugly. Tried several variants of `rapply` and `purrr` mutants without success. Any ideas?

```
# Generate data 
el = function(){
  a = rnorm(runif(10 + 3))
  class(a) = "bt"
  a
}

ell = list(el(), el())
class(ell) = "bt_list"

d = list(el(), el(), ell)
str(d)

# Unpack the list in data
ret = list()
i = 1
for (dd in d) {
  if (is(dd, "bt_list"))
  {
    for (d in dd) {
      ret[[i]] =  d
      i = i + 1 
    }
  } else {
    ret[[i]] = dd
    i = i + 1
  }
}

str(ret)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly hacky approach: Nest everything to the same level, then use `purrr::flatten`:

```r
library(purrr)

d %>% modify_if(Negate(is.list), list) %>% flatten() %>% str()
#> List of 4
#>  $ :Class 'bt'  num [1:13] -0.4432 -0.8113 0.0909 1.5127 -1.1452 ...
#>  $ :Class 'bt'  num [1:13] -0.222 -0.3307 -0.0342 -0.0497 -1.3101 ...
#>  $ :Class 'bt'  num [1:13] 1.004 -0.146 0.325 0.307 0.389 ...
#>  $ :Class 'bt'  num [1:13] -0.327 1.434 -1.187 0.759 1.193 ...
```

Comment: Clever. Will have to wait a few minutes till I can accept this. Looks like modify_if was not on my screen.

Comment: It's mostly a renaming of `map_if` (which still exists for now), but keeps class, so it can be used on data.frames or other objects non-destructively.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R method with `lapply`. It checks if the element is a list, if yes returns the element, if no returns a list of length 1 containing the element. Then `unlist` with recursive=FALSE is fed to it to unnest the list. Note that the code will work for a list of max depth 2 as in the example. I suspect that there may be a method to implement this recursively, but I don't attempt it here:

```
unlist(lapply(d, function(x) if(is.list(x)) x else list(x)), recursive=FALSE)
[[1]]
 [1]  0.9066792 -1.3454847 -0.8537010  1.3674898 -1.2739962 -0.6985093 -1.2859386  1.4084817
 [9] -0.7793395 -1.4975101 -1.0413126  1.0787356 -0.3256806
attr(,"class")
[1] "bt"

[[2]]
 [1] -0.570994422  1.097478529  0.682345735 -0.260428116  0.354880308  1.114958954
 [7] -1.025245415 -0.391107246  0.008361003  0.246687656  1.083959863 -2.071394617
[13] -0.717595486
attr(,"class")
[1] "bt"

[[3]]
 [1] -1.1984306  0.9337199 -0.6019184 -2.4940949 -1.3929918  1.4996909  0.1669178  1.7971318
 [9]  1.4406508  1.5093291 -0.8680647 -0.3412633 -0.4315870
attr(,"class")
[1] "bt"

[[4]]
 [1] -1.05771596 -1.25278104 -1.35396929  1.96866094 -1.88897210  1.54753633 -0.20623455
 [8]  1.26695133 -1.27460182  0.96117381  0.14783072  0.93768848  0.03364427
attr(,"class")
[1] "bt"
```

Comment: That's fine, there is no deeper nesting in my case.